# The XAML Designer unhandled exception. (Exit code: e0434352)

Tags: xaml, unhandled-exception, xaml-designer

I've run into an unhandled exception in in the XAML designer in Visual Studio.
It simply won't load any XAML files and gives me following error:

[Screenshot of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSOtQ.png)

Visual studio was at version 17.6.3 when the error happened, I've tried upgrading to 17.6.4 and 17.7 preview 2, but the problem persists.

It was just "there" from one day to another, I can't figure out why.

I've tried cleaning visual studio cache files, deleting all obj and bin folders in the solution.
I've tried upgrading and downgrading vs studio, I've even reinstalled it.
Lastly I tried checking out an older version of the project that I knew worked, but it still fails.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message you are facing. Share all details in text form, not hidden in screenshots